# How to set auto zoom in angular google map (AGM)

Tags: angular, google-maps, agm

How to set auto-zoom in angular google map (AGM), that is based on the address entered it should change zoom level automatically, for example, if I entered the country it should show the overall country map when I am entering a particular street or address it should show street level. I do this based on the length of the formatted address object, is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to achieve this is to **[GEOCODE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)** the input and **then parse the 0 index of the address components array instead of the formatted_address**.

For example, the algorithm was able to detect a "street_address" in the components, then there should be an equivalent zoom level for that. With regards to your use case, everything is in the address_components. You can set zoom level for each: street_address, locality, administrative_levels, country.

Below is a sample code (via vanilla javascript):

```
  geocoder.geocode(
    {
      address: address
    },
    function(results, status) {
      if (status === "OK") {
          results.map(function(value, key){
                console.log(value.address_components[0].types); // 0 index type
          });
      } else {
        alert(
          "Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +
            status
        );
      }
    }
  );
```

Based on my observations, these are the best zoom levels for each address component. Please note that the zoom level may also depend on the s*ize of the street/city/state/country*.

- street_address = 16 to 18
- city = 15
- state = 12
- country = 5

Hope this information finds you useful and good luck on your project!

Comment: Thanks for the reply rafon, this is how I done but my question is how to set auto zoom?, I don't want to set this values manually.